# Force WhenAnyValue to re-evaluate

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Is there a clean way to force a WhenAnyValue to re-evaluate itself and call onNext for its subscribers?

```
    protected override IObservable<bool> IsDirty() {
        return this.WhenAnyValue 
        (x => x.Firstname,
         x => x.LastName
        (f1, f2) => 
        f1 != this.Model.FirstName
        || f2 != this.Model.LastName
        );
    }

    protected override void SaveModel() {
        Model.FirstName = this.FirstName;
        Model.LastName = this.LastName;
        Save(Model); 
        // want to force IsDirty to re-evaluate here and return false.
    }
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your solution with subject will work, I believe you can do better that that. I'm assuming that the code you presented is taken from a view model. Given that assumption:

1) [`SaveModel` should be a Command](https://github.com/reactiveui/rxui-design-guidelines#commands)

2) [`IsDirty` should be an output property](https://github.com/reactiveui/rxui-design-guidelines#prefer-observable-property-helpers-to-setting-properties-explicitly)

If you apply this changes, you end up with a code without additional `Subject` (yay!)

```
// in class
public ReactiveCommand<Unit> SaveCommand { get; }

private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isDirty;
public bool IsDirty { get { return _isDirty.Value; } }


// in constructor
this.SaveCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => 
{
    Model.FirstName = this.FirstName;
    Model.LastName = this.LastName;
    Save(Model); // this could be an async method
    return Task.FromResult(Unit.Default);
});

this.WhenAnyValue(
    vm => vm.Firstname,
    vm => vm.LastName,
    (f1, f2) => Unit.Default)
    .Select(_ => this.FirstName != this.Model.FirstName 
              || this.LastName != this.Model.LastName)
    .Merge(this.SaveCommand.select(x => false))
    .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.IsDirty, out _isDirty);
```

This uses the fact that `ReactiveCommand` itself implements `IObservable` holding same information as your subject.

Comment: Cheers man - I see what you've done there. That's much cleaner. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I thought it should be easy. I must have been 'pre coffee' this morning.

```
protected Subject<Unit> Saved = new Subject<Unit>();

protected override IObservable<bool> IsDirty() {
        return this.WhenAnyValue 
        (x => x.Firstname,
         x => x.LastName
        (f1, f2) => 
        f1 != this.Model.FirstName
        || f2 != this.Model.LastName
        ).Merge(Saved.Select(x => false));
}

protected override void SaveModel() {
    Model.FirstName = this.FirstName;
    Model.LastName = this.LastName;
    Save(Model); 
    this.Saved.OnNext(new Unit());
}
```